# template match contains string or apply templates?

Tags: xslt, match

I got a XML Code looking like this:

```html
  <student_list>
 <student name ="Pete">
  <text v ="3. Grade (relevant) skilled in Maths."/>
  <text v ="But often sleeps."/>
 </student>
 <student name =" Laura">
  <text v ="Biology kid (relevant)."/>
  <text v =""/>
 </student>
 <student name="Audrey">
  <text v ="Both inspired by Biology and Maths."/>
 </student>
 <student name="Mario">
  <text v ="Both inspired by Biology and Maths (relevant)."/>
 </student>
</student_list>
```

What I want to achieve is:
Extracting all students by name show their relevant subjects seperated.
"Relevant" is an indicator for if it's necessary to show this kid's subjects or not.   If relevant appears in the context, then show the subjects, otherwise not.
As I only want to compare two subjects for the beginning (biology and maths), I want to say that if one subject is missing and the context is relevant then please mention that the kid is not skilled in the other missing subject.
The output should be sorted by the subjects.
Concrete this should produce the following output:
Pete: Skilled in Maths
Laura: Not Skilled in Maths
Mario: Skilled in Maths
Pete: Not Skilled in Maths
Laura: Skilled in Biology
Mario: Skilled in Biology

Can someone help me to achieve this?
I am using XSLT 1.0
I was thinking about to match all students and do couple of tests to check if the text-attributes contains specific values, but that's pretty Java-Coding style, not really procedural, so I'm sure this can be done better, quicker and easier. But I don't know how to afford it.

Comment: Are you able to use scripting as well? This would be hard with pure xslt.

Comment: Where would the list of subjects (Math, Biology...) come from?

Comment: No, unfortunately no scripting is allowed. The List of subjects is implemented in the xml and should be extended manually.

Comment: "*List of subjects is implemented in the xml and should be extended manually.*" No idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Well, the user type it in the XML manually.

Comment: XSLT processes the supplied XML document. Either the list of subjects is already there, or it isn't (in your example, it isn't) There is no opportunity for a "user" to "type it in manually". In fact, there is no "user" in this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this can help:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<my:subjects>
    <subject>Math</subject>
    <subject>Biology</subject>
</my:subjects>

<xsl:template match="/student_list">
    <xsl:variable name="students" select="student[contains(text/@v, 'relevant')]" />
    <xsl:for-each select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:subjects/subject">
        <xsl:variable name="subject" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="$students">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="text[contains(@v, $subject)]">Skilled in </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>Not skilled in </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:value-of select="$subject"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
Pete: Skilled in Math
 Laura: Not skilled in Math
Mario: Skilled in Math
Pete: Not skilled in Biology
 Laura: Skilled in Biology
Mario: Skilled in Biology
```

Comment: Thank your sir for the approach. Unfortunately everything seems to be falling into "Not skilled in.." but I try to fix this by my own if I grasp it.

Comment: That's not result I get (see above).

Comment: Oh yea, I got it done, had to change a thing to fit it to the whole XML file.  Thanks again